# What is jwplayer.jwpsrv.setSampleFrequency

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I noticed that http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/jwpsrv_frq.js

changed from

```
jwplayer.jwpsrv.setSampleFrequency(0.001);
```

to

```
jwplayer.jwpsrv.setSampleFrequency(0);
```

anyone knows what this is? I can't find any documentation on it

Answer (score 1):

This call was previously configured for internal testing, but has been deprecated in JW7. It will be deprecated in JW6 as well.